# C++17 Structured binding for class member with this operator

Tags: c++, this, c++17, class-members, structured-bindings

Why C++17 structured binding do not like the `this->` operator in is a syntax like this one :

```
std::tuple<int, std:string> external_function()
{
    return { 0, "" };
}

class Foo
{
public:
    void internal_method()
    {
        auto [this->x, unused] = external_function();
    }

private:
    int x;
};
```

How to add a class member specifier to the returned variable names?

Comment: From what I understand structured bindings are supposed to introduce new local variables, not assign multiple returned values to multiple existing variables.

Comment: So that's why the compiler (vs2017 in my case) do not like the `this->` operator. It's bad to add a simplification enhancement and do not allow to do this type of operation. Thank you for your answer

Comment: @MaximeCoorevits: For existing variables, `std::tie` is still an option, but yes, there is a gap between "all existing" and "all non-existent" that isn't covered.

Comment: @MaximeCoorevits: "*Structured binding only create local variable and do not allow a direct access to class member.*" No, Structured binding only creates local variables, and therefore cannot assign to *any* existing variable, whether a class member, global, local, etc. That's why your question is a duplicate; class members are a subset of "any existing variable".

Comment: @Nicol Bolas. Thank you. Do I need delete my question?

Comment: @MaximeCoorevits: There's nothing wrong with a duplicate. Some are even quite useful, since searching can lead to the original question.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas. Thank you. Have a good day.